# How to insert blank space in HTML which will not be copied

Tags: html, css

I want to insert some blank spaces in a line, but I don't want those blank spaces will be copied when the viewer select those...

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: for space just add (&nbsp;) -- that's a space. probably you need some javaScript to trim the spaces off when you select the text  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin i would disagree, its not a duplicate since that is about no highlights and this is about copying. but there isn't any way to do what the user requested I think

Comment: @ AlexeiDarmin  -- thats not selecting text at all the OP does not want the spaces coppied

Comment: @Tasos well trim only work at the beginning and end to begin with and then you'll have to capture "cntrl-c" and/or "command-c" and override the functionality, personally i'm against hijacking such standard functionality

Comment: my suggestion is to take a spacer div/span and then add margin to it to space the needs.....

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have made myself clear. Similar to what the answer below suggests, I imagined you do a `no select` class on each space. Then when the user tries to select text the spaces would be ignored. However the answer below also accounts for `ctrl + C` and `cmd + C` so it's even better.

Comment: ok i undestand what you mean. You can use word-spacing http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp

Answer (score 4):

is it helpful?

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <style>
    .space{margin-left:50px}
  </style>
  <body>
    hello <span class="space"></span>world
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nifty hack, I approve